# splitting row data based on condition

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am getting result set for the below query

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN S.TaxableAmt <= 2000 THEN '<=2000'
          WHEN (S.TaxableAmt >= 2001 AND S.TaxableAmt <= 3000) THEN '2001-3000'
          WHEN (S.TaxableAmt >= 3001 AND S.TaxableAmt <= 4000) THEN '3001-4000'
          ELSE '>5000'
       END as Bracket,
COUNT(DISTINCT(S.INVOICENO)) AS LESSTWO , YEAR(S.invoicedate) YER, 
    Month(S.invoicedate) MNTH
FROM SALESDATA S 
where S.BILLINGTYPE='INVOICE' 
    AND (S.invoicedate >='20090401' and S.invoicedate <='20100430')
GROUP BY
      CASE
          WHEN S.TaxableAmt <= 2000 THEN '<=2000'
          WHEN (S.TaxableAmt >= 2001 AND S.TaxableAmt <= 3000) THEN '2001-3000'
          WHEN (S.TaxableAmt >= 3001 AND S.TaxableAmt <= 4000) THEN '3001-4000'
          ELSE '>5000'
       END,
YEAR(S.invoicedate) ,Month(S.invoicedate) 
ORDER BY YEAR(S.invoicedate) ,Month(S.invoicedate)
```

as below

```
BRACKET      LESSTWO   YER  MNTH
3001-4000   331 2009    4
>5000   562 2009    4
<=2000  21271   2009    4
2001-3000   1351    2009    4
<=2000  20008   2009    5
3001-4000   325 2009    5
2001-3000   1307    2009    5
>5000   470 2009    5
<=2000  24486   2009    6
3001-4000   381 2009    6
>5000   449 2009    6
2001-3000   1465    2009    6
<=2000  49624   2009    7
>5000   548 2009    7
2001-3000   1836    2009    7
3001-4000   478 2009    7
<=2000          54828   2009    8
2001-3000   2552    2009    8
>5000   1265    2009    8
3001-4000   888 2009    8
>5000   524 2009    9
2001-3000   1597    2009    9
<=2000  30684   2009    9
3001-4000   508 2009    9
>5000   731 2009    10
2001-3000   2376    2009    10
<=2000  31032   2009    10
3001-4000   691 2009    10
>5000   1693    2009    11
2001-3000   3532    2009    11
3001-4000   1227    2009    11
<=2000  29895   2009    11
>5000   1314    2009    12
3001-4000   996 2009    12
<=2000  30018   2009    12
2001-3000   3438    2009    12
>5000   2225    2010    1
2001-3000   3243    2010    1
<=2000  56189   2010    1
3001-4000   1428    2010    1
>5000   1590    2010    2
2001-3000   2541    2010    2
3001-4000   1017    2010    2
<=2000  48069   2010    2
>5000   584 2010    3
3001-4000   551 2010    3
<=2000  30094   2010    3
2001-3000   1577    2010    3
<=2000  27552   2010    4
3001-4000   459 2010    4
>5000   505 2010    4
2001-3000   1788    2010    4
```

But I need result set like below.

<2000  (2001-3000) (3001 - 4000)  >5000  LESSTWO   YER  MNTH ====> as column headings.

How can I do this?

Regards,

N.SRIRAM

Comment: Having that DISTINCT() in there is worrying me - do we have to deal with an invoice that might match more than one bracket - i.e. one row with TaxableAmt <= 2000, and another row for the same invoice, but TaxableAmt > 2000?

Answer (score 0):

Do I get you correct qassuming you like to group and have each group sum as a column instead of a row?

n that case have a look on [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)